# Salesforce1 Mobile Card

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile, redirect, urlfor

I have created a visualforce page that is essentially a button that will be placed on a Contact's page. When pushed it will redirect the user to another visualforce page and carry along the contact id. I have added this visualforce page to the mobile card section of the corresponding layout. Here is what it looks like from the salesforce1 emulator
[image]

The problem that I am facing is that when I try to click the button it takes me to a brand new page with just the button where I have to click it again in order for it to redirect.

[image]

Here is the code for the button

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Contact">
  <apex:outputLink styleClass="btn" value="{!URLFOR($Page.MobileContactContactAddRelationship, contact.id)}">
    <apex:outputText value="Create Relationship"/>
  </apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

So does anyone know why the button will go to a new page where I have to reclick it?

Comment: Same issue i'm facing. I assume this is the default behavior of mobile enabled visualforce pages.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be the default behavior for mobile cards. I ended up going with a publisher action to make the UI better

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of the Mobile Cards, where the Mobile Card simply shows a preview of the Visualforce page. Once clicked, you are redirected to the full Visualforce page.